# Labelled Trees on $n$ vertices

Tags: trees

Let *f* : [*n*] → [*n*] be a function, and let *T*<sub>*f*</sub> be a labelled tree on *n* vertices, constructed from *f*. Suppose that *T* contains a vertex of degree at least *k*. Show that *f* takes at most *n*-*k*+2 different values.

I don't really know how to start here.

Thanks.

Comment: A usual way to define a tree from $f\colon [n] \to [n]$ is to take $f$ to be the function that gives the parent of a node.  One node of the tree is the root and has no parent.  Is this your setup?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I know the following, and that's kind of how we defined it : The map *f* → *T*  associates to every function *f* as above, a labelled tree *T* on *n* vertices with 2 vertices marked as red and blue. The number *i* belonging to [*n*] can be a leaf of *T* if and only if *i* is not a value of *f*, or either red or blue vertices. Do you see the setup ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.  What are these two special vertices doing?  Could you add an example to your post?